# ISNULL(int, ' ') Empty string returns 0, is there a way to override?

Tags: sql-server

```
CAST(c.CNumber AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.'
            + CAST(cc.Card AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.'
            + CAST(CASE WHEN ce1.Id IS NOT NULL
                   THEN ISNULL(cerp.CERP, ' ')
                   ELSE ISNULL(cpa.Port, ' ')
              END AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [IDPool]
```

Let's say CNumber is 3, and Card is 50, the display for this query would be 3.50.0 The problem is I need to find a way to override data type precedence and first listed variable restrictions present in ISNULL and COALESCE. I can't have that last number be 0, I need it to display nothing. I've tried casting to no avail. Maybe this isn't even possible to do?

EDIT - apologies, first post and I looked elsewhere.

if ce1.Id is not null, then if cerp.CERP is null I need to pass an empty string, so the result should be, let's say 3.50. But because ISNULL takes the datatype of the first passed argument (in this case an int) it converts that empty string to a 0 resulting in 3.50.0 The problem is I can't have it be a 0 on the end

Comment: uhm, what?, what's the result you actually need?

Comment: So you want `3.5` or `3.50` or `3.50.`  ? I'm confused.

Comment: Even a little bit of clear explanation would go a LONG way to getting an answer here.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: if ce1.Id is not null, then if cerp.CERP is null I need to pass an empty string, so the result should be, let's say 3.50.   But because ISNULL takes the datatype of the first passed argument (in this case an int) it converts that empty string to a 0 resulting in 3.50.0 The problem is I can't have it be a 0 on the end.

Comment: Then convert your number to a varchar.

Comment: as I said I tried casting, and I can't go back and change the data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the parameter values inside of the `ISNULL` function instead of the outside of the function so that the result type of the function is the type you want.  Also, if you do not want the period to show up when the values are null you can include the string concatenation inside the `ISNULL` function as well so that they disappear.

```
declare @CNumber as int = 3
declare @Card as int = 50
declare @Id as int
declare @CERP as int
declare @Port as int

select 
    CAST(@CNumber AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.'
        + CAST(@Card AS VARCHAR(2))
        + CASE WHEN @Id IS NOT NULL
               THEN ISNULL('.' + cast(@CERP as varchar(2)), '')
               ELSE ISNULL('.' + cast(@Port as varchar(2)), '')
          END AS [IDPool]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this did the trick, ISNULL only takes two parameters so I didn't even think to concatenate inside the function. Apologies for the question being so unclear, and thanks again!

Comment: No problem; glad to help!  Yeah, you can use expressions as parameters for functions, but not stored procedures.  Welcome to SO :)  If you find an answer useful you can click the checkbox next to it to mark it as the accepted answer to let people know it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand...sure isn't very clear on this side of the internet.

```
CAST(c.CNumber AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.'
            + CAST(cc.Card AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.'
            + CAST(CASE WHEN ce1.Id IS NOT NULL
                   THEN ISNULL(convert(varchar(2), cerp.CERP), ' ')
                   ELSE ISNULL(convert(varchar(2), cpa.Port), ' ')
              END AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [IDPool]
```

Comment: This is how I understood the question.